# Sql Server: Raise warnings and collect them

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2016, sql-server-2019, raiserror

I need to raise one or more warning messages inside a child stored procedure and then collect all of them in the parent one.
I tried with
`RAISERROR('Message 1',0,0) WITH NOWAIT`
but it doesn't work at all (`ERROR_MESSAGE()` is NULL in the code below).

I wish something like code below, which is not working.

It doesn't have to be `RAISERROR`, any solution is accepted.

```
create procedure test_child
as begin
    RAISERROR('Message 1',0,0) WITH NOWAIT;
    RAISERROR('Message 2',0,0) WITH NOWAIT;
    RAISERROR('Message 3',0,0) WITH NOWAIT;
end
;

create procedure test_parent
as begin
    declare @err nvarchar(max);

    exec test_child;
    set @err = error_message();
    select @err
end
;

exec test_parent;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe storing your warnings in a table variable and returning that could fit your needs?

```
drop procedure if exists myproc_that_returns_warnings
go

create proc myproc_that_returns_warnings
as
    declare @warnings table
    (
        id int identity(1,1),
        msg varchar(255),
        severity int
    )

    declare
        @msg varchar(255),
        @severity int

    set @msg = 'first warning'
    set @severity = 1

    /*first warning*/
    insert into @warnings(msg, severity)
    values(@msg, @severity)

    /*second warning*/
    insert into @warnings(msg, severity)
    values('second warning', 2)

    select * from @warnings
go


drop table if exists #warnings
create table #warnings
(
    id int,
    msg varchar(255),
    severity int
)
go
insert into #warnings
exec myproc_that_returns_warnings
```

If it's possible you could also turn the proc into a table valued function to achieve the same end result.

Comment: I want to avoid refencing to a table in every procedure. I can execute a stored like dbo.proc_Log but it's not the best. In both solution, with a rollback I will loose every message.

Comment: If I remember correctly table variables aren't affected by rollbacks, gotta try it to be sure though.

Answer (score 1):

You won't be able to use the error handling mechanisms in SQL Server to communicate more than one error message. There's no "error collection" (or whatever) that you can loop in the calling code to get to each individual error message.

Also, ERROR_MESSAGE() will be null if it isn't called in a CATCH block. From the product documentation:

> ERROR_MESSAGE returns NULL when called outside the scope of a CATCH
> block.

I suggest you have the proc inserting relevant data into a table and the calling code can now examine that table.

Erland's article on sharing data between stored procedures might be useful:
https://www.sommarskog.se/share_data.html

Comment: I want to avoid refencing to a table in every procedure. I can execute a stored like dbo.proc_Log but it's not the best. In both solution, with a rollback I will loose every message.

Comment: A table variable isn't affected by rollback.